# ¿Cómo cambiar la ip de docker?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Tengo la siguiente situación:

Estoy en la empresa y `Docker` carga por defecto el `Bridget` que me da la `IP` `192.168.99.100`, debido a las políticas de seguridad del `firewall` de la empresa, dicha `IP` no tiene conexión a internet.

Me gustaría saber como puedo cambiar la configuración de red de `docker-machine` para asignarle una `IP` con acceso a internet o en su defecto que utilice la `IP` de mi equipo físico así como el adaptador puente de `Virtual Box`.

Estuve revisando la documentación de `Docker` pero la verdad no comprendo como realizar el cambio.

Mi sistema Operativo es `Windows 7`. Por lo que trabajo con la terminal `Docker`.

Comment: fijate si la VM "default" en virtual box manager tiene los 2 adaptadores activados, uno tiene que ser NAT (y darle internet) el otro es host only (visible sólo para el host). como alternativa podes activarle un tercer adaptador en modo bridge y ver que pasa, o configurar un proxy

Comment: @aloMalbarez, siguió igual, sin cambio :/

Comment: humm no tengo disponible un box win 7 pero creo recordar que desde el administrador de conexiones podes hacer un bridge enlazando 2 placas de red. la otra que se me ocurre es ver la configuración dhcp del host only (preferences del VM manager) y decirle que asigne direcciones dentro del rango que tu firewall acepta (medio como configurar un router como AP sin uplink)

Answer (score 2):

Según la documentación tendrías que acceder al daemon.json donde está definido el default bridge y modificar la configuración por la que necesites. Debería ser algo así por defecto en tu caso:

```
{
  "bip": "192.168.99.100/24",
  "fixed-cidr": "192.168.99.100/25",
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8::/64",
  "mtu": 1500,
  "default-gateway": "192.168.1.1",
  "default-gateway-v6": "2001:db8:abcd::89",
  "dns": ["10.20.1.2","10.20.1.3"]
}
```

Tendrías que modificarlo por ips que si aceptaran el firewall de tu empresa.

Aquí puedes encontrar información acerca de dónde y cómo modificar el daemon.js en Windows: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon

Comment: Saludos Alvaro, Gracias por contestar, el asunto es que como tengo `Docker` en `windows 7`, estoy utilizando es `Docker Toolbox` a pesar de que cree el archivo, no hubo ningún efecto.

Comment: Pásate por este post, puede ser que te resulte de ayuda: https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/638

Comment: para la ip, lo mas importante es el "bip" los otros parametros no son estrictamente necesarios

Answer (score 1):

En mi empresa también utilizamos docker, y solo pueden cambiar la IP el departamento de sistemas por seguridad, pero si no me equivoco, en el script que lanza el container (compose-up) tu mismo puedes realizar varios cambios en la configuración del contenedor, si tienes permisos para ello

Comment: Yo cuento con las `ip` de acceso, el problema radica en que el contenedor esta usando un `bridge` y genera la ip `192.168.99.100` para los contenedores, no se como cambiar la configuración para que no tome la `ip` del `bridge`, intente crear un `machine generic` pero no obtuve resultados.